# Encrypting root partition with LUKS2 and TPM

Tags: systemd, luks, tpm

I aim to encrypt the root partition and protect the key with TPM. Eventually, I want to lock the encryption key to the state of the TPM registers.
I set up Fedora Workstation 38 - during the setup wizard, I checked the box to encrypt the drive and provided a recovery phrase - this worked as expected - during the boot phase, I was prompted for a passphrase to unlock the LUKS key. Below is the output of `lsblk -pf`.

```
lsblk -pf
NAME                                                   FSTYPE      FSVER LABEL                 UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sr0                                                                                                                                           
/dev/zram0                                                                                                                                         [SWAP]
/dev/vda                                                                                                                                           
├─/dev/vda1                                                                                                                                        
├─/dev/vda2                                            ext4        1.0                         b8d2cbbf-0f44-4487-bccf-74d9365ec383    647M    27% /boot
└─/dev/vda3                                            crypto_LUKS 2                           08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6                
  └─/dev/mapper/luks-08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6
                                                       btrfs             fedora_localhost-live 09d81602-3093-4a76-8c56-d9562197cdb9   13.2G    27% /home
```

Next, I enrolled TPM:

```
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --tpm2-device=auto /dev/vda3
New TPM2 token enrolled as key slot 1.
```

At this point I have two keyslots: 0 - password and 1 - TPM.

Next, I updated the `/etc/crypttab`:

```
luks-08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6 UUID=08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6 - tpm2-device=auto
```

Next, I reloaded systemd `systemctl daemon-reload`, below is the updated service file.

`sudo systemctl cat systemd-cryptsetup@luks\\x2d08ab0fc7\\x2d5a6b\\x2d421c\\x2dbe8a\\x2dd6171761a3e6.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Cryptography Setup for %I
Documentation=man:crypttab(5) man:systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8) man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
SourcePath=/etc/crypttab
DefaultDependencies=no
IgnoreOnIsolate=true
After=cryptsetup-pre.target systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
Before=blockdev@dev-mapper-%i.target
Wants=blockdev@dev-mapper-%i.target
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=cryptsetup.target
BindsTo=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-08ab0fc7\x2d5a6b\x2d421c\x2dbe8a\x2dd6171761a3e6.device
After=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-08ab0fc7\x2d5a6b\x2d421c\x2dbe8a\x2dd6171761a3e6.device
Before=umount.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=0
KeyringMode=shared
OOMScoreAdjust=500
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 'luks-08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6' '/dev/disk/by-uuid/08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6' '-' 'tpm2-device=auto'
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach 'luks-08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6'
```

I rebooted my system and it came-up OK; I still provided my password - as expected.

Next, I wiped-out the password:

```
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --wipe-slot=password /dev/vda3
wiped slot 0.
```

Rebooting causes the following error (appologies for a screenshot).
[image]

When I examined the systemd-cryptsetup@luks.. service (after booting into the rescue mode), I noticed that the `ExecStart` no longer had TPM patameters:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 'luks-08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6' '/dev/disk/by-uuid/08ab0fc7-5a6b-421c-be8a-d6171761a3e6' '' ''
```

The `systemctl status` of the service produced the following error message: `systemd-cryptsetup[630]; No passphrase or recovery key registered`.

`

I found the problem, thank you @u1686_grawity

I had to add a step - `dracut -f` after adding a TPM slot - this (I believe) loaded TSS driver early in the boot process.

Comment: In place of screenshots, please share the log entries generated by kernel and relevant systemd units.

Comment: Does the Fedora **initramfs** (dracut) include TPM2 drivers? Can you check its contents in /boot, or get more details out of dracut about what it's including? Do not wipe out the password; you'll still need it (or a "recovery key" slot) if TPM2 unsealing fails for any reason – which _will_ happen in regular use.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, thank you @u1686_grawity

I had to add a step - `dracut -f` after adding a TPM slot - this (I believe) loaded TSS driver early in the boot process.